# Typescript, mongoose toObject returns any

Tags: typescript, mongoose, types

```
interface User {
  _id: GooseTypes.ObjectId;
  email: string;

}

interface UserDoc extends User, Document {
  _id: GooseTypes.ObjectId;
}


const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
});

const UserModel = model<UserDoc>("User", UserSchema); 
const userDocument = new UserModel({email: "test@test.com"}); //returns UserDoc type
const userObject = userDocument.toObject(); // returns any, have to manually cast to User
```

Currently I'm using @types/mongoose. I want to avoid doing toObject() as User because this introduces place for mistakes.

> How can I extend toObject() method to return an object of type User/OtherType?

Comment: It was already `UserModel` type before calling `toObject`. What are you trying to do converting it to "object"?

Comment: Before toObject() it is UserDoc type, DOC. When it is UserDoc type, when testing with jest it compares it wrong "Compared values have no visual difference" but because of all the extra magic on the Document type it says the objects are different. When I do toObject() it strips down all the extra methods